# Microsoft SQL Server Error 102

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am executing below query and it gives me

```
SELECT
  t1.s_reference "Section",
  t2.m_reference "CourseRef",
  t2.m_name "CourseName",
  t3.mi_q02m02 "Aim",
  t2.m_level "Level",
  t2.m_start "Start",
  t2.m_end "End",
  t2.m_projstudents "Target",
  COUNT(DISTINCT t4.e_id) "Enrolled"
FROM
  isr t3,
  person t5,
  department t6,
  section t1,
  enrolment t4,
  course t2
WHERE
  t3.mi_id(+)=t2.m_id
  AND t4.e_module=t2.m_id
  AND t4.e_student=t5.p_id
  AND(t2.m_status LIKE '%%'||SUBSTR((TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY')+DECODE(least(to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm')),8),8,0,-1)),-2,2) ||'%%')
  AND t2.m_reference LIKE 'LL%%'
  AND t4.e_status IN('C','S')
  AND to_date(t2.m_start,'DD-Mon-RRRR')<=to_date(sysdate,'DD-Mon-RRRR')
  AND to_date(t2.m_end,'DD-Mon-RRRR')>=to_date(sysdate,'DD-Mon-RRRR')
  AND t2.m_modulesection=t1.s_id
  AND t2.m_moduledept=t6.d_id
  AND NVL(t2.m_close,0)=0
  AND t3.mi_q02m02 IS NOT NULL
  AND((
  CASE
    WHEN((t1.s_reference='LL2a')
      AND(t2.m_reference LIKE '%W%'))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END)=0)
  AND(t2.m_reference!='LL3036E15')
GROUP BY
  t1.s_reference,
  t2.m_reference,
  t2.m_name,
  t3.mi_q02m02,
  t2.m_level,
  t2.m_start,
  t2.m_end,
  t2.m_projstudents,
  t1.s_reference,
  t2.m_reference
ORDER BY
  t1.s_reference,
  t2.m_reference
```

An error occurred while executing the query.

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'. MS SQL Server Error 102
```

I ran the same query in SQL Developer and it runs fine.

I tried to remove most of the parenthesis but still doesn't help.
Any idea why this happens?

Thanks
Aruna

Comment: Which row is the problem one? (Remove code that works fine, and keep the smallest possible problem query.)

Comment: (probably) unrelated to your error, but you should switch to explicit `join` syntax, it's the standard since 1992!

Comment: Of course you are getting errors.  You have written Oracle code and you are getting a SQL Server error.  You should write the code using SQL Server conventions.

Comment: Replace concentration function  "||"  with " + '' + "

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`. The functions you use don't even exist in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to run a query written for Oracle in Microsoft's SQL Server. These products use a slightly different dialect of SQL, which are incompatible. For example, `DECODE`, `NVL`, `TO_CHAR` are not available in SQL Server. You'll have to re-write the query using SQL Server functions to replace the Oracle specific ones (`CASE`, `COALESCE`, `CONVERT` for the ones I mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

1st step... replace all || to the word OR

2nd step

> AND(t2.m_status LIKE
>   '%%'||SUBSTR((TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY')+DECODE(least(to_number(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm')),8),8,0,-1)),-2,2)
>   ||'%%')

where

> ||'%%')

is not a qualified condition and may be irrelevant since you already used it

3rd

> t3.mi_id(+)=t2.m_id

you have to re-write this

4th

> %%

should only be %

Comment: I replaced || with OR but I get invalid relational operator error

Comment: Too many things to convert to sql server syntax like to_char etc. you need to rewrite them.